# An object acquiring mutex in destructor to prevent deletion of itself

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

Can this concept work?

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    ~MyClass()
     {
         MyMutex.acquire();
     }

     void ThreadFunction(void* param)
     {
          MyMutex.acquire();
          //do something
          MyMutex.release();
     }

};
```

Also Let's say we have an object of this class, call it `"inst"`

What I am trying to achieve is that if:

- One thread is active and executes `inst->ThreadFunction`
- Another Thread is calling `delete inst` then this call will hang until ThreadFunction releases the mutex.

Is that ok to do?

Comment: Prevent deletion of which object?

Comment: It is not preventing the deletion. It is just waiting until MyMutex is acquired.

Comment: @dbasic Yes this is the idea... Is that OK to do?

Comment: woolstar has already raised few points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be much better to create a wrapper around `MyClass` if `MyClass` contains resources.  Its even worse if the program uses a class that inherits from `MyClass`, because the destructor for `ChildofMyClass` will have already been called by this point.